# How to return all positives and the first negative number in a list using functional programming?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Imagine I have an unsorted list of positive & negative ints. I want to return a list containing all the positive ints, and the first negative number, but then ignore all subsequent negative numbers from the list, while preserving the ordering.

Imperatively I could do:

```
l = [1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3]
out = []
first = true
for n in l:
    if n >= 0:
        out.push(n)
    else if first:
        out.push(n)
        first = false

// out = [1, 2, -4, 5, 3]
```

How could I do this with FP in Scala? I was thinking (probably won't compile...):

```
val l = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)
val posl = l.map(_ >= 0)
val negl = l.zipWithIndex.map((n, i) => if (n < 0) (i, n) else (None, None)).head
// now split posl at negl._1, and create a new list of leftSlice :: negl._2 :: rightSlice?
```

Is this the right approach, or is there a more elegant, succinct way?

Comment: What do you mean by the first negative number in an unordered list? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "unordered list".  Lists are inherently ordered -- it's what makes them lists, and what makes the word "first" make any sense.  You probably mean "unsorted".  </pedantry>

Comment: @cHao yes i meant unsorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a tail-recursive way. Compared to m-z's answer, it iterates your list only one time, compared to Dimas answer, it does not use mutable state, so it is pure functional.

```
def firstNegAllPos(list: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
  def loop(in: List[Int], out: List[Int], negfound: Boolean) : List [Int] = {
    in match {
      case Nil => out
      case head :: tail =>
        if (negfound)
          loop(tail, if (head < 0) out else head :: out, true)
        else
          loop(tail, head :: out, head < 0)
    }
  }
  loop(list, Nil, false)
}

firstNegAllPos(List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)) // List(3, 5, -4, 2, 1)
```

**Edit**:

The above implementation provides a reversed result. In order to preserve order you can do following:

```
def firstNegAllPos(list: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
  def loop(in: List[Int], out: List[Int], negfound: Boolean) : List [Int] = {
    in match {
      case Nil => out
      case head :: tail =>
        if (negfound)
          loop(tail, if (head < 0) out else head :: out, true)
        else
          loop(tail, head :: out, head < 0)
    }
  }
  loop(list, Nil, false).reverse
}

firstNegAllPos(List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)) // List(1, 2, -4, 5, 3)
```

Comment: It's not as succinct as I was hoping, but it's performant and pure functional, so is the best solution for me, thanks!

Comment: `out :+ head` O(N), making it O(N^2) overall. It would be better simply to call `.reverse` on the result of your first version

Comment: I like it, but I feel like it really hides it's true nature.

Comment: Can it be faster to call `filter(_ >= 0)` for remaining positive numbers after the first negative value is found? `filter()` usually  runs faster.

Answer (score 10):

It wouldn't be a proper functional programming question without a slightly-too-clever recursion+pattern matching answer.

```
def firstNegAllPos(l:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
   l match{
      case x::xs if x>=0 => x::firstNegAllPos(xs)
      case x::xs if x<0 => x::xs.filter(_>=0)
      case Nil => Nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Should be `>=0` in the filter?

Comment: I like that one, though it lacks of tail-recursion.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in one pass provided you don't mind keeping a bit of state around - mind the `var neg`:

```
var neg = false
list.filter { 
    case x if x > 0  => true
    case _ if !neg   => neg = true
}
```

Comment: A good example to show **mutable** value makes code concise and easy to read!

Answer (score 6):

A direct translation of the requirement is pretty clear, takes one pass over the list, and is functional:

```
val l = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3) 

// split into any initial positive numbers, and the rest of the list 
val (pos, firstneg) = l.span(_ >= 0)

// if there were no negative numbers, return the original list.
// otherwise, it's the initial positives, the first negative, and
// the positive numbers from the rest of the list.
if (firstNeg.isEmpty) l else pos:::List(firstneg.head):::firstneg.tail.filter(_>=0)
//> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, -4, 5, 3)
```

(The `List` around `firstneg.head` is just for the symmetry of `:::` both sides)

Answer (score 4):

```
val l = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3) 
val (left, right) = l.span(_ > 0)
val result = right.headOption match {
    case Some(n) => (left :+ n) ++ right.tail.filter(_ > 0)
    case None => left
}
```

Comment: In one line: `l.span(_>0) match { case (left, right) => right.headOption.fold(left)(n => (left :+ n) ++ right.tail.filter(_>0))}`

Answer (score 4):

This is an obvious work for fold operation!

```
val l = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)

var result = l.foldLeft((true, Vector.empty[Int])) {
  case ((f, r), x) if x >= 0 => (f, r :+ x)
  case ((f, r), x) if f => (false, r :+ x)
  case ((f, r), x) => (f, r)
}._2

println(result)  // Vector(1, 2, -4, 5, 3)
```

I used a vector as an intermediate structure; you can convert it to a list with `toList`, if you need it. Or you can use it instead of the `Vector`, but you will have to reverse the addition order (`r :+ x` => `x :: r`) and then reverse the list in the end with `reverse` method.

Comment: I considered this, but the use of a flag to hold whether we've seen a negative is pretty much equivalent to having a state variable, IMO.

Comment: Yes, it is, but with a fold that state is encapsulated and can be changed only in one way.

Comment: Sure. It doesn't (IMO) result in clear understandable code though. I think this problem inherently splits into "do something until we see a negative number, then do something else with the rest of the list", and  that gets a bit lost with the foldLeft.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the order (i.e., the position of the negative), you could do something like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)
val negIndex = list.indexWhere(_ < 0)
val positive = list.zipWithIndex.filter { case (num, index) =>
    num >= 0 || index == negIndex
}.map(_._1)
```

The negative requirement makes it hard to keep it more succinct than that. My strategy is to just grab the index of the first negative with `indexWhere` (will be -1 if there is none), then `filter` all the negatives out of the list, except for the index of the first negative. If the index was -1, no harm, no foul.

Comment: This is better than my attempt but a similar approach. I guess there's no way to do it with a single pass over the list as with the imperative approach?

Comment: You could include the `indexWhere` within the `filter` somehow, but that wouldn't really be better, and certainly not more efficient. I still wouldn't call this an imperative approach, though.

Comment: @jbrown there is a way using single pass. Just have a look at my pure functional approach. Or take Dimas if you are fine with some mutable state (which is not pure functional then)

Answer (score 2):

Here is tail recursive solution preserving order:

```
  def posNeg(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(tail: List[Int], res: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      tail match {
        case h :: t =>
          if (h >= 0) go(t, h :: res)
          else (h :: res).reverse ::: t.filter(_ > 0)
        case _ => res
      }
    }
    go(xs, Nil)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tail-recursive solutions, but they're all longer than they need to be.

```
def oneNeg(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def loop(in: List[Int], out: List[Int], neg: Int): List[Int] = in match {
    case Nil => out
    case x :: rest =>
      if (neg < 0 && x < 0) loop(rest, out, neg)
      else loop(rest, x :: out, x min neg)
  }
  loop(xs, Nil, 0).reverse
}
```

If this is not a public-facing API, you can make it shorter yet by just exposing the inner method alone:

```
def oneNeg(in: List[Int], out: List[Int] = Nil, neg: Int = 0): List[Int] = 
  in match {
    case Nil => out.reverse
    case x :: rest =>
      if (neg < 0 && x < 0) oneNeg(rest, out, neg)
      else oneNeg(rest, x :: out, x min neg)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improvement on the most concise answer I saw, by @sschaef in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668713/how-to-return-all-positives-and-the-first-negative-number-in-a-list-using-functi#comment43757182_27670031):

```
val l = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)

l.span(_>=0) match { case (left, Nil)      => left
                     case (left, x::right) => left ++ (x +: right.filter(_>=0)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
val list = List(1, 2, -4, 5, -6, -1, 3)
val index = list.indexWhere(_ < 0) + 1
list.take(index) ++ list.drop(index).filter(_ > 0)
```

Comment: yes this does that, takes the index of the first negative element (implicit --> all elements before that).

Comment: And to quote his sentence: " I want to return a list containing all the positive ints, and the first negative number, "

Comment: When I run this in the REPL I only get List(1,2,-4) as the result (and that's changing l.indexWhere to list.indexWhere). The list isn't sorted don't forget and I want to preserve the original ordering.

Comment: That's just doing more passes for no reason. Your `list.take` is better as `list.takeWhile (_>0)`  (there's no reason to pre-caclulate the index) and then since you're doing the drop (better as dropWhile( as well, you get to `span`, which some other solutions already have. If you really want to use the index, see `splitAt`.